# Check JSON/YAML fields with annotations on deserialization with Jackson?

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, annotations, lombok

I hava a simple Java class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MyClass {
    @JsonProperty("field1")
    public String field1;
    @JsonProperty(value = "field2")
    public int field2;
```

Annotations on a class belongs to Lombok and on fields - to Jackson.

I deserialize my, for example, YAML object to `MyClass` using following code snippet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(args[2]));
o = mapper.readValue(data, MyClass.class);
```

I have tried different annotations like Lombok's @NonNull, Jakarta's @NotNull/@Min/@Max, but I cannot obtain the desired result, namely, I wish to control fields of a `MyClass` on deserialization process and stop processing if fields are invalid. As an example could be `min/max` values, `required` value, `not null` value etc. So far, all these annotation that I have tried to add didn't take an effect at all and seems like all these checks left aside.

Is there any annotations that will fire during that deserializtion process?

Cheers!